# Response Code 422 Retrofit

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'm trying to do a simple authentication with my laravel api. But unfortunately in my android studio project, it's returning a response code 422.

Here is my code in my API:

**LoginController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
       $this->validateLogin($request);

            if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
                $user = $this->guard()->user();
                $user->generateToken();

                return response()->json([
                    'data' => $user->toArray(),
                ]);
            }
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

Then here is in my web interface in Android Studio:

**BizWebService.java**

```
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json"
    })
    @POST("api/login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<LoginResponse> login(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password);

class LoginResponse extends ServiceResponse {
        @SerializedName("message")
        public String message;

        @SerializedName("errors")
        public ArrayList<Email> errors;

        @SerializedName("data")
        public ArrayList<DataItems> data;
    }

    class DataItems {
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        public int id;

        @SerializedName("username")
        @Expose
        public String username;

        @SerializedName("api_token")
        @Expose
        public String api_token;

        @SerializedName("whoToVote")
        @Expose
        public String whoToVote;

        @SerializedName("created_at")
        @Expose
        public String created_at;

        @SerializedName("updated_at")
        @Expose
        public String updated_at;
    }

    class Email {
        @SerializedName("email")
        @Expose
        public String email;
    }
```

**Module class:**

```
public class Module {

    public static void register(BizApplication application) {
        BizWebService api = createWebService(application);

        new LiveAccountService(api, application);
        new LiveCandidateService(api, application);
        new LiveCriteriaService(api, application);
    }

    private static BizWebService createWebService(BizApplication application) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new AuthInterceptor(application.getAuth()))
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BizApplication.API_ENDPOINT.toString())
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .build();

        BizWebService webService = retrofit.create(BizWebService.class);
        return webService;
    }

    private static class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

        private final Auth auth;

        private AuthInterceptor(Auth auth) {
            this.auth = auth;
        }

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            if (auth.hasAuthToken()) {
                request = request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.getAuthToken())
                        .build();
            }

            long t1 = System.nanoTime();
            Log.i("Request", String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
                    request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));

            Response response = chain.proceed(request);

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                return response;
            }


            if (response.code() == 401 && auth.hasAuthToken()) {
                auth.setAuthToken(null);
            }

            long t2 = System.nanoTime();
            Log.i("Response", String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
                    response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers()));


            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**LiveAccountService.java**

```
public class LiveAccountService extends BaseLiveService {

    private final Auth auth;


    public LiveAccountService(BizWebService api, BizApplication application) {
        super(api, application);

        auth = application.getAuth();
    }


    @Subscribe
    public void loginUserRequest(Account.LoginRequestRequest request) {
        Call<BizWebService.LoginResponse> call = api.login(request.Username, request.Password);
        call.enqueue(new RetrofitCallback<BizWebService.LoginResponse>(BizWebService.LoginResponse.class) {
            @Override
            protected void onResponseSuccess(Call<BizWebService.LoginResponse> t, Response<BizWebService.LoginResponse> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        return;
                    } else {
                        Account.LoginRequestResponse response1 = new Account.LoginRequestResponse();
                        response1.setOperationError("Error");
                        bus.post(response1);
                        Log.e("Server Error", Integer.toString(response.code()));
                    }
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried posting the request in Postman and it works.
I don't have an idea where I did wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem firstly. Send a mock-up with data you know is correct to the laravel backend, see if that works. If it does, then the problem itself lies in the mobile part, if not, the problem lies in the laravel part.

Comment: How about debugging after this if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) { as of now return something in json and check whether it is returning data or not, also if service is OK, then please check in REST API Client like postman

Comment: I tried posting the request using Postman and it works but it doesnt work when I pass the request in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is an old post of mine but I just want to share on how I solved the problem. It's not really THE solution but it helped me either way in solving my problem.

Basically, my core problem was that I could not see the requests and responses that I've been throwing at my web service so I installed a 3rd party library which monitors the requests that I throw and the responses that I receive from the server. It's the HttpLoggingInterceptor. Then I added it as one of the interceptors in my OkHttpClient object in the`createWebService` method. Right then, I was able to monitor the requests and responses and I was able to send the right and acceptable data to the server.